# Unable to add html attributes using html helper - MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using Html helper class to create radio button. It is working as it is expected, but when I tried to add custom html attribute it is not adding in html.

What I am expecting:
I want to create 4 radio buttons which should work in exclusive manner.

1. Show All Items from SAP Business One
2. Show only those items whose UDF (U_WebItem=Y) value is Yes"
3. Show All Items from below selected Item Group
4. Show All Items from Business Partner Catalogs
   The above 4 item would be my radio buttons and only one will be selected rest all will be unselected.

From my DB side, there is only one field called "ItemManagedBy" whose values are fixed(ALL,UDF,ITG & BPC). Depending on the value it should select the correct radio button.

Here is my controller method:

```html
 Models.CRMSettings ReadCRMSettings(Tenant tenant)
        {
            Models.CRMSettings crmsetting = new Models.CRMSettings();
            CRMCommonDataContext db = new CRMCommonDataContext(General.COMMONConnectString);
            var v =(from v1 in db.TenantSettings where v1.TenantID.Equals(tenant.TenantID) select v1).First();

            crmsetting.SaveCustomerAsInactive = v.SaveCustomerAsInactive.HasValue ? v.SaveCustomerAsInactive.Value : false;
            crmsetting.SaveLeadAsInactive = v.SaveLeadAsInactive.HasValue ? v.SaveLeadAsInactive.Value : false;

            crmsetting.SettingID = v.SettingID;
            crmsetting.TenantID = v.TenantID.Value;
            
            crmsetting.PurchaseItemManagedBy = v.PurchaseItemManagedBy;
            crmsetting.SalesItemManagedBy = v.SalesItemManagedBy;
            
            switch(crmsetting.SalesItemManagedBy)
            {
                case "ALL":
                    crmsetting.IsSalesItemManagedByAll=true;
                    break;
                case "UDF":
                    crmsetting.IsSalesItemManagedByUDF = true;
                    break;
                case "ITG":
                    crmsetting.IsSalesItemManagedByITG= true;
                    break;
                case "BPC":
                    crmsetting.IsSalesItemManagedByBPC = true;
                    break;
            }
            switch (crmsetting.PurchaseItemManagedBy)
            {
                case "ALL":
                    crmsetting.IsPurchaseItemManagedByAll = true;
                    break;
                case "UDF":
                    crmsetting.IsPurchaseItemManagedByUDF = true;
                    break;
                case "ITG":
                    crmsetting.IsPurchaseItemManagedByITG = true;
                    break;
                case "BPC":
                    crmsetting.IsPurchaseItemManagedByBPC = true;
                    break;
            }
}
```

```html
 @model saasCRM.Models.CRMSettings

    @{
        Layout = null;
        var htmlAttrib = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        htmlAttrib.Add("name", @Model.RadioGroup);
        htmlAttrib.Add("binding", "true");
        htmlAttrib.Add("datamember", "Response>Data");
    }

      <table style="width:100%;border:1px solid red">
       @{
          <tr>
             <td>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsSalesItemManagedByAll, Model.IsSalesItemManagedByAll ? "selected" : "", htmlAttrib)
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsSalesItemManagedByAll)
            </td>
          </tr>
        }
        </table>

Output of this is :

<input name="IsSalesItemManagedByAll" id="IsSalesItemManagedByAll" type="radio" value="selected" datamember="Response>Data" binding="true" data-val-required="The Show All Items from SAP Business One field is required." data-val="true">

<label for="IsSalesItemManagedByAll">Show All Items from SAP Business One</label>
```

Attribute like datamember and binding is available, but why it change the name property

Any help on this.

Am I using it in wrong way?

Here is my Model:

```html
 public class CRMSettings
    {
        public string RadioGroup { get; set; }
        public int SettingID { get; set; }
        public int TenantID { get; set; }
        public bool SaveCustomerAsInactive { get; set; }

        public bool SaveLeadAsInactive { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// ALL, UDF,ITG ,BPC
        /// </summary>
        public string SalesItemManagedBy { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// ALL, UDF,ITG ,BPC
        /// </summary>
        public string PurchaseItemManagedBy { get; set; }

        public CRMSettings()
        {
            RadioGroup = "ItemSettings";
        }

        public IEnumerable<MasterData> ItemGroups { get; set; }


        #region "For Radio Button"
        
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Show All Items from SAP Business One")]
        public bool IsSalesItemManagedByAll { get; set; }
        
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Show only those items whose UDF (U_WebItem=Y) value is Yes")]
        public bool IsSalesItemManagedByUDF { get; set; }
       
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Show All Items from below selected Item Group")]
        public bool IsSalesItemManagedByITG { get; set; }
       
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Show All Items from Business Partner Catalogs")]
        public bool IsSalesItemManagedByBPC { get; set; }




        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsPurchaseItemManagedByAll { get; set; }
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsPurchaseItemManagedByUDF { get; set; }
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsPurchaseItemManagedByITG { get; set; }
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsPurchaseItemManagedByBPC { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to change the `name` attribute which means that model binding will fail? If you want to bind to property `RadioGroup` then use `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=> m.RadioGroup)`

Comment: And setting the `value` attribute to either `"selected"` or `null` based on the value of the property makes no sense. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: In real scenario, there are 4 radio buttons, only one of them will be selected at a time. that's why I need a name property to make it mutually exc. At the backend there is only one db field. Depending on the value radio button should select

Comment: Then use `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=> m.RadioGroup, someValue)` which will bind to property `RadioGroup` but you model makes no sense in relationship to your view and I assume your not understanding how to use a radio button group. And your use of `Model.IsSalesItemManagedByAll ? "selected" : ""` means it will all fail anyway. Best guess is you want to select from `IsPurchaseItemManagedByAll ` or `IsPurchaseItemManagedByUDF` etc? If so, edit you question to make it clear what your trying to do

Comment: You already have a property `SalesItemManagedBy` so delete all those pointless `boolean` properties and use `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SalesItemManagedBy, "All")` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SalesItemManagedBy, "UDF")` etc. Then the value of `SalesItemManagedBy` will be either "All", "UDF", "ITG" or "BPC" depending on which radio button you selected (although I recommend you use an `enum` to define the possible values rather than `string`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating thing.

Essentialy, if I understood it correctly, you want to populate 4 radio button which is checked base on value.

If so, just do:

```
// your viewmodel

public class CRMSettings
{
  // represent the 4 value of radio button
  public string ItemStatus {get; set;}
}
```

then in your view just do

```
// represent 4 radio button
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ItemStatus, "ALL" )
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ItemStatus, "UDF" )
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ItemStatus, "ITG" )
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ItemStatus, "BPC" )
```

in your controller

```
model.ItemStatus = "" // one of the 4 value you want radio to be preselected
```

Just to clarify a little more:

because you only get one value per group of radio button, hence only need one property for a group of radio button, and you change the select by setting the value of the radio button into property. Then when you call HtmlHelper in view, it does all the rest of making all 4 radio as a group by having same name (hence one property)

Comment: Thanks you make it very much simple, My code was too complex

Answer (score -1):

Please try to do like this

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsSalesItemManagedByAll, Model.IsSalesItemManagedByAll ? "selected" : "",new {@class="TempClass" , @name="SalesManage"})

In HTML helper you need to HTML attributes new object in that  you can declare all HTML attributes with '@' prefix.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried this also, but it add @name attribute instead of name Please see this <input name="IsSalesItemManagedByAll" id="IsSalesItemManagedByAll" type="radio" value="selected" data-val-required="The Show All Items from SAP Business One field is required." data-val="true" @name="ItemSettings" @datamember="Response>Data" @binding="true">

Comment: IN that case problem is something else because for me it coming like this

 @Html.RadioButton("isDOc", "Documnets", new { @class="TempClass" })


<input name="isDOc" class="TempClass" id="isDOc" type="radio" value="Documnets">